# how to put div below header div and above footer div with full height html

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to `reactjs`. I have a page which has `3` block of `divs`.

Here's the Page
[My Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVic6.jpg)

Here's the Code I tried:

```
  return (
    <div  >
     {/* First Block */}
        <div style={{ padding: "0.8%", backgroundColor:"red" }}>
            Block 1
        </div>
{/* Second Block */}
        <div style={{ height: "40%", overflowY: 'scroll', backgroundColor: "aqua", position: "fixed", width: "100%" }} >
       Block 2
        </div>

    {/* Third Block */}

      <div style={{ display: "flex", position: "fixed", bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0, height: "40px", backgroundColor: "grey", }}>

           Block3
      </div>

    </div>
  );
```

`Block 1` is a the Header Block.`Block 2` is the Content Block. `Block 3` is the Footer Block. .I fixed `Block 1` on Top and `Block 3` on bottom. Now I want my Block 2 to fit in the middle with full height. I can give height as manual to Block 2. But there are lot of screen sizes out there. It becames a messy process for me. I want to make Block 2 to fit it in it for all screen sizes. How can I achieve this.I searched Stackoverflow but I can't able to fix it. Please help me with some solutions.

Output I need:
[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyZDd.png)

Comment: This can easily be done with flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Header and Footer will be fixed. Only Center Content will be scrollable

```
 <div style={{ display:"flex", backgroundColor: "green", height: "100vh" , flexDirection:"column", flex:1}}>
      {/* First Block */}
      <div  style={{backgroundColor:"red",  width: "100%"}}>
        Block 1
      </div>
      {/* Second Block */}
      <div style= {{background: "pink",display:"block", overflow: "auto", flex:1}}>
        Block 2
        An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument, but the definition is vague, overlapping with those of a letter, a paper, an article, a pamphlet, and a short story. Essays have traditionally been sub-classified as formal and informal. Formal essays are characterized by "serious purpose, dignity, logical organization, length," whereas the informal essay is characterized by "the personal element (self-revelation, individual tastes and experiences, confidential manner), humor, graceful style, rambling structure, unconventionality or novelty of theme," etc.[1]

Essays are commonly used as literary criticism, political manifestos, learned arguments, observations of daily life, recollections, and reflections of the author. Almost all modern essays are written in prose, but works in verse have been dubbed essays (e.g., Alexander Pope's An Essay on Criticism and An Essay on Man). While brevity usually defines an essay, voluminous works like John Locke's An Essay Concerning Human Understanding and Thomas Malthus's An Essay on the Principle of Population are counterexamples.

In some countries (e.g., the United States and Canada), essays have become a major part of formal education. Secondary students are taught structured essay formats to improve their writing skills; admission essays are often used by universities in selecting applicants, and in the humanities and social sciences essays are often used as a way of assessing the performance of students during final exams.

The concept of an "essay" has been extended to other media beyond writing. A film essay is a movie that often incorporates documentary filmmaking styles and focuses more on the evolution of a theme or idea. A photographic essay covers a topic with a linked series of photographs that may have accompanying text or captions
An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument, but the definition is vague, overlapping with those of a letter, a paper, an article, a pamphlet, and a short story. Essays have traditionally been sub-classified as formal and informal. Formal essays are characterized by "serious purpose, dignity, logical organization, length," whereas the informal essay is characterized by "the personal element (self-revelation, individual tastes and experiences, confidential manner), humor, graceful style, rambling structure, unconventionality or novelty of theme," etc.[1]

Essays are commonly used as literary criticism, political manifestos, learned arguments, observations of daily life, recollections, and reflections of the author. Almost all modern essays are written in prose, but works in verse have been dubbed essays (e.g., Alexander Pope's An Essay on Criticism and An Essay on Man). While brevity usually defines an essay, voluminous works like John Locke's An Essay Concerning Human Understanding and Thomas Malthus's An Essay on the Principle of Population are counterexamples.

In some countries (e.g., the United States and Canada), essays have become a major part of formal education. Secondary students are taught structured essay formats to improve their writing skills; admission essays are often used by universities in selecting applicants, and in the humanities and social sciences essays are often used as a way of assessing the performance of students during final exams.

The concept of an "essay" has been extended to other media beyond writing. A film essay is a movie that often incorporates documentary filmmaking styles and focuses more on the evolution of a theme or idea. A photographic essay covers a topic with a linked series of photographs that may have accompanying text or captions
An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument, but the definition is vague, overlapping with those of a letter, a paper, an article, a pamphlet, and a short story. Essays have traditionally been sub-classified as formal and informal. Formal essays are characterized by "serious purpose, dignity, logical organization, length," whereas the informal essay is characterized by "the personal element (self-revelation, individual tastes and experiences, confidential manner), humor, graceful style, rambling structure, unconventionality or novelty of theme," etc.[1]


      </div>
      {/* Third Block */}

      <div  style = {{marginTop:"auto", backgroundColor:"grey"}}>

        Block3
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a header footer body then

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin:0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Style the header */
header {
  background-color: #666;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

/* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px; /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Style the list inside the menu */
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

article {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px; /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
section::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the footer */
footer {
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 
<header>
  <h2>Cities</h2>
</header>

<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
  </article>
</section>

<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the Cities and Footer to be fixed. only center content should be scrollable

Comment: try using adminlte they give free dashboard https://adminlte.io/  with sidebar and header with footer

Comment: csslayout.io here you will find all layout https://csslayout.io/sticky-footer/ https://csslayout.io/sticky-header/